Using LIKE with % when executing SQL queries with placeholders for parameters
I have a project with PostgreSQL database where queries are stored in SQL files and executed using namedParameterJdbcTemplate#queryForList method. Meaning that parameters are stored in the queries using placeholders, for example:
WHERE 1=1
and ( CAST ( rf.date AS varchar ) = :date OR 'getAll' = :date )
and ( CAST ( krr.id AS varchar ) = :id OR 'getAll' = :id )

And for passing the parameters into the query, we use a Map<String, Object>.
My question is, how can I use this mechanism to search for substrings using LIKE %something%? Trying to pass a parameter formatted like "%something%" doesn't work, altering the query to use CONCAT with % and parameter doesn't work either, I'm getting syntax error every time. The % sings are evidently the problem here, I can search fine without them but of course that will only result exact matches.

Can you share an example of the concatenation and the syntax error you're getting for it?

Side note: The pattern you are using might be pretty bad for performance: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic
